# What kind of utf8 encoding is being used in members of String class in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

`String` class has a constructor:

```
 new String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)
```

and a method:

```
 byte[] getBytes(Charset charset)
```

Given that I define my `charset` as follows:

```
 Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
```

What kind of encoding I will in fact use? More specifically is it a standard UTF-8 (as described in [RFC 3629](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629.html)), or [CESU-8](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr26/), or [Modified UTF-8](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8)? (See also corresponding [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8))

In case if it's not a standard UTF-8 is there a library that allows String operations in utf8?

A converter for these UTF-8-derived encodings is more than welcomed!

Comment: It's right there in the javadocs for Charset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The UTF-8 charset is specified by [*RFC 2279*](http://ietf.org/rfc/rfc2279.txt); the transformation format upon which it is based is specified in Amendment 2 of ISO 10646-1 and is also described in the [*Unicode Standard*](http://www.unicode.org/unicode/standard/standard.html).

http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Comment: For the record RFC 3629 is more or less a "corrected" version of RFC 2279.